Was Norton utilities the first disk defragmenter?
I thought HDD defragmentation was the cleverest thing I had ever seen in computers since college. It improved the performance so much and it had been completely overlooked. At least by me.
Does the amazing Norton deserve this adulation, or did somebody else think of it first? I certainly never heard about it in IBM mainframe disks.
The coolest part was all the options it gave you for rearranging things on the disk, like putting all The system files together near the FAT to limit head motion, and move your large media files to the end of the drive.

And "defragmentation" existed before PCs by necessity on file systems without allocation tables, e.g. UCSD Pascal, back to OS/8 DECtape. So the idea wasn't new; doing it for speed improvements instead or reclaiming fragmented space was new.

"I certainly never heard about it in IBM mainframe disks" Usually a proof that operations had disk organisation well planned and maintained transparent to usage, It all depends ofc. on application profile and file type used. Mainframe applications are usually planning disk usage ahead of time and allocate disk space - and extend size - as needed. Also mainframe databases are usually reorganised routinely. Defragmentation is only needed for files without por badly planned growth and no planned reorganisation. Like typical for chaotic PC usage :))

Not sure if you remember right. System files of DOS were generally unmovable, and when you partitioned a drive and formatted the system partition, the first two files copied on disk were the two system files (IO.SYS and MSDOS.SYS) and thus they were located right at the start of disk and could never become fragmented or moved anywhere by defrag programs as they already were the two contiguous files located at start of data area.

The need to defragment disks has always existed, as long as there has been moving-head disks.
On many PDP-11 systems, once you noticed that the disk cabinets were vibrating sideways due to violent head motion :-), it was time to run 'disc save and compress'.  Typically you'd roll out the file system to tape, wipe the disc, and roll the tape content back in.  Since you were dealing in files (not disk blocks) the file system would allocate contiguous space.
If you want online defragmentation, then RT-11 had a particularly simple file system, in which any file was a single extent. This led to having unusable discontiguous disk space.  The command PIP DK0: /S would 'squeeze' everything to low disk addresses, defragmenting the free space and putting the allocated space in adjacent tracks. This only took a few minutes since the typical RT-11 disk was an RK05 1MB (if I recall correctly) single-platter cartridge.
This is all 1970s stuff.


, it was time to run 'disc save and compress'. ==== ROLOUT and ROLBAK! I remember! They copied the entire 90M  fastrand drum to tape and then copied it back in immediately. I thought that was real clever too, but it never occurred to me that it would do defragging.


It depends whether it works on the disk-block level or the file-system level. DEC had both types of utility on various systems. 'DSC' was, I think, the first one that rewrote file system metadata on restore, thus making it able to defrag.

I don't know when disks or drums were first managed as persistent "files", but I'm pretty sure that the first moving-head systems predate any such notions, and would instead perform operations as "move to track 19; load sector 12", with track 19 always being located between tracks 18 and 20.  I also strongly suspect that file systems that could automatically find space for files were preceded by systems where files could be identified by name, but needed to have contiguous regions of storage assigned to them via manual or quasi-manual process (e.g. loading a concatenated sequence of files...

...from tape and/or card stacks to a continuous range of disk blocks, and then indicating the location of the last block used).

RT-11 used contiguous files. The allocation system was "on creation, first hole large enough to contain programmer-specified size", with truncation down to actual written length on normal close.  Not quite manual, but you had to be aware of what was going on.  Which was fine, since RT-11 was a single-user system.  I think a 'hole' was essentially the same as a file, i.e, it had a directory entry giving start and size.

Norton Utilities Speed Disk was introduced in version 4.0, released in 1987. It was not the first disk defragmenter for PCs: I’m aware of at least two earlier disk defragmenters.
The earliest PC defragmenter I know of is SoftLogic’s Disk Optimizer, first released in 1984 or 1985 (the floppy disk has a copyright date of 1984, but the manual is dated 1985 and the first mentions in the press are in 1985).
Even in the shareware world, G. Allen Morris III’s Disk Organizer (DOG) was first published in 1986.

AMOS, the Alpha Micro Operating System, 1977, an S-100 system running on a Western Digital WD-16 CPU, supported two distinctly different kinds of files on disk. This scheme required frequent defragmentation using a program called REORG.
Random access files, typically of a fixed size and used as database storage, were allocated to a contiguous block on disk, preferentially at the high track addresses. By knowing the base address for the file and the record size, the OS could jump directly to a particular record without reading through the entire file sequentially.
Sequential access files, which as the name says could only be read sequentially, were used for text, programs and command files. They were discontinuous, with blocks stored in any available space, and in no particular order, preferentially at low track numbers, with each data block linked to the next by disk address.
Frequent read/write, create/delete activity would leave a disk map looking like Swiss cheese. Though empty blocks might be available and scattered all over the disk, if one wanted to create a new random access file, one needed contiguous empty space.
Enter REORG. It packed all the random access files toward the high track numbers and sequential access files toward the low track numbers, leaving a contiguous empty space in the middle tracks.

Depending exactly what counts as defragmentation, the DFS (Disk Filing System) for the BBC Micro might count.
DFS was a fairly simple filesystem, and stored each file in contiguous sectors — so there was no opportunity for files to become fragmented.  However, the empty space between files could and did get fragmented, and so the *COMPACT command was used to collect all the free space together by relocating all files to the start of the disk.
This didn't necessarily improve performance, but was necessary to allow all the disk to be used, avoiding Can't extend errors.
The first DFS release was in 1982 from Acorn.  (Other companies later released their own implementations.)  I think the same applied to the later ADFS too, at least in BBC Micro series implementations.  (Some later RISC OS versions supported fragmentation.)

Same sort of thing as the RT-11 file system.

This isn't quite the same as DEFRAG's volume-level cleanup, but OS/360's IEBCOPY utility allowed the user to copy a partitioned data set (PDS) in place, moving all free space to the end of the data set. This is similar in concept to defragmenting a disk volume.
The earliest reference to this feature in documentation that I can find is in NASA's Mission and Data Operations IBM 360 User's Guide, section 9.3-1 / p.224 from July 1973.
